# Openflow Multipart Request Error Message: OFPBRC_BAD_LEN (6)

Tags: python, lua, wireshark, mininet, openflow

Long story short, I have a project that requires me to create a controller from scratch in python and handle requests from switches created through a mininet topology following the Open Flow Protocol.

Helpful Open Flow Protocol resources:

- https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-switch-v1.5.1.pdf
- http://flowgrammable.org/sdn/openflow/message-layer/
- http://flowgrammable.org/sdn/openflow/message-layer/statsrequest/#ofp_1_3

My code is available here on github for cloning and full transparency:

- [removed as of 10/12/2019, see my answer below]

The issue I am running into is that I am unable to send a multipart-request message for the port stats description (search `PortDesc` on this [link](http://flowgrammable.org/sdn/openflow/message-layer/statsrequest/#ofp_1_3)). I do not know why this is the case, but when I view the packet data in wireshark I get a "Range is out of bounds" error. I haven't been able to figure out why this is the case. Here are a few screenshots of the packet data:

**Wireshark captures:**
[image: Bytes where I created the multipart request]
[image: Openflow multipart request mess]
[image: Full screenshot of the openflow protocol]

**Lua error messages:**
[image: Lua error message part 1]
[image: Lua error message part 2]

**Bad Request Error Message Response:**
[image: Bad request error message response]
[image]
Something to note here is that the code says `OFPBRC_BAD_LEN (6)`, but the length of bytes sent in the multi-part request are of size 16.

A classmate that sent their packet data correctly has said that they were using the same packing structure that I am, except theirs is successful (see the python [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) documentation). I don't know what the issue could be with mine and I am running out of ideas to check. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

TL;DR: I am unable to send a multipart request and even though I am adhering to the request specifications, results keep returning with an error code. Error in wireshark says "Range out of bounds" and I do not know how else to structure my request to correct this error message.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, but I don't think I have an answer as to what the problem was. First I'll start with my solution, and then talk about what I believe the problem is.

**Solution:**

As you can see in the screenshots above, I was sending OpenFlow packets in the version 1.5 protocol, which is the newest version, but visiting [openflow message layer documentation](http://flowgrammable.org/sdn/openflow/message-layer/) only shows documentation up to 1.4.

Ontop of that, the latest version of multipart request that the documentation shows is 1.3.1. Even when I send a multipart request for Open Flow Protocol version 1.5 it wasn't showing up as the OpenFlowProtocol, instead as a regular TCP packet. I did the following 3 things:

1. In my topology file, where I create the switch, I was initializing
   the switches as `s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1')`. What I added to this
   statement was the protocol parameter:  `s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1',
   protocols='OpenFlow14')`.
2. For good measure I also added `protocols` specification to the
   mininet command in the console:  `sudo mn --custom mytopo.py --topo
   mytopo
   --controller=remote,ipaddr=127.0.0.1,port=6653,protocols=OpenFlow14`
3. I also changed how I was packing the requests, so instead of
   specifying version 1.5 (which is a '06' in the packet header), I
   packed it as 1.4 (which is a '05' in the packet header). `req =
   struct.pack('!BBHI',5,5,8,0)` (ex. for the `feature_request` message
   sent to the switch).

These steps solved the issue I was running into and I was able to get a `stats_reply` from the switch.

**Problem (or what I think the problem is):**

I believe the problem was that AS OF RIGHT NOW, Open Flow Version 1.5 doesn't have support yet for the multipart request, as evidenced by when sending a multipart request for the port description, it shows a regular TCP protocol instead of the OpenFlow protocol.